# How to make a generic function value?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
interface Foo<T1> {
  foo: string;
  baz: T1;
}

function toFoo<T2>(value: T2): Foo<T2> {
  return {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: value
  };
}

// Actually this function is imported from an NPM package so I can't change it
// The example is given for a better illustration
function memoize<T3, T4>(func: (arg: T3) => T4): (arg: T3) => T4 {
  // Some implementation...
  return func;
}

const memoizedToFoo: {<T5>(value: T5): Foo<T5>} = // ???
```

The `toFoo` function is a generic. I need to make a memoized version of `toFoo` that is a generic too. I can't change the `memoize` type and implementation. How to implement `memoizedToFoo` so that it matches the given interface?

I try this, but it doesn't work:

```
const memoizedToFoo<T5> = memoize(toFoo<T5>); // unexpected <T5>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you change your `memorize()` function? It is working too hard.

The following will automatically infer the right type:

```
interface Foo<T1> {
  foo: string;
  baz: T1;
}

function toFoo<T2>(value: T2): Foo<T2> {
  return {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: value
  };
}

function memoize<F extends Function>(func: F): F {
  // Some implementation...
  return func;
}

const memoizedToFoo = memoize(toFoo)
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Foo%3CT1%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20baz%3A%20T1%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20toFoo%3CT2%3E(value%3A%20T2)%3A%20Foo%3CT2%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20'bar'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20value%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20memoize%3CF%20extends%20Function%3E(func%3A%20F)%3A%20F%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Some%20implementation...%0A%20%20return%20func%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20memoizedToFoo%20%3D%20memoize(toFoo)%0A)

UPDATE: Since you can't change `memorize()`, you can override it nicely as follow:

```
// memorize.ts
import { memoize as origMemoize } from 'memoize'
// or if it is commonJS
import origMemoize from 'memoize'

export const memoize = origMemoize as <F extends Function>(func: F) => F
```

Then you can use it just as the original:

```
import { memoize } from './memoize'

// code away
```

Note that this solution does tradeoff some type safety because `F` is not restricted to `(arg: X) => Y`

To properly address this, we need:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22368

Comment: You answer is great but I can't change the `memoize` function because I import it from another library, I forgot to mention it in the question.

Maybe I can cast the imported function to your type, e.g.: `const properMemoize = memoize as <F extends Function>(func: F) => F`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the memoized function with `any` generic argument (if required) and cast it to the generic function type:

```
const memoizedToFoo: <T5>(value: T5) => Foo<T5> = memoize(toFoo);
// or
const memoizedToFoo: typeof toFoo = memoize(toFoo);
```